# UITableView has problems scrolling after upgrading to iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I just noticed now that I've updated my app to iOS 5, that when my tableview has fewer cells than fit the screen, it doesn't scroll, but if I click a cell to go to detail view, and then pop back to the table, it scrolls fine.  Also, if I initially have more cells than fit on the screen, it scrolls fine from the start.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the screen would fit 4 cells and 3 are displayed, why would you expect it to scroll?

Comment: the cells are supposed to be scrollable no matter how many cells are there.  it was always like this before iOS5.  Also, I have 6 cells in one view, but the 6th cell is only halfway on the screen, and it doesn't scroll so I can't see the full cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Nib for the VC. XCode 4.2 has made some changes  to IB and the way tables are dealt with, so that's probably where you issue lies.

Hope that helps.